# For every polynomial $p$ find a matrix $A$ such that $p(A)=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

For every $p(x)\in F[x]$ where $F$ is a field , can we always find a integer $n$ and a matrix $A\in M_n(F)$ such that $p(A)=0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes : Take the companion matrix of the coefficients of $p$.

Comment: \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & -c_0 \\
1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & -c_1 \\
0 & 1 & \dots & 0 & -c_2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \dots & 1 & -c_{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: I added the explicit form of the companion matrix only for future references